# Should there be an apostrophe in "Ladies' Coats" on the sign in a shop selling ladies' coats?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

I work in a charity shop and we sell coats for ladies. Should the sign read "Ladies' Coats" or "Ladies Coats"? I argue for the apostrophe but some of my friends argue that as the coats do not belong to the ladies yet that there shouldn't be an apostrophe.

Answer (score -1):

Your friend is correct, before they are purchased the coats belong to the *business*, and not to the *ladies* who will be purchasing them to add to their wardrobe.

So the sign should read

> Ladies Coats

For example:

See this wording from a [high street retailer](http://clothing.boden.co.uk/clothing/Ladies-Coats):

> Ladies Coats

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but that is not true! Strictly speaking, the apostrophe _should_ be used because the coats are of a style intended for women. Whether they are currently in the possession of ladies is irrelevant. However, there is a tendency nowadays to leave out final apostrophes for the sake of neatness, which is what the website has done.